# Is there a function to generate a sequence of number of days since the first date recorded in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr, lubridate

I am trying to analyze the survival probability of a plant. So, I recorded every 8 days the survival/dead of each plant for 3 months. I have a dataframe like this:

```
   sampling date       ID    survival
1        1 04/03/2017 L4           0
2        1 04/03/2017 L5           0
3        1 04/03/2017 L6           0
4        2 15/03/2017 L4           0
5        2 15/03/2017 L5           1
6        2 15/03/2017 L6           0
7        3 23/03/2017 L4           0
8        3 23/03/2017 L6           1
```

Where: Survival is a binomial vector: 1= alive, 0= dead. ID= id of each plant. Date= date of sampling.
I tried many different combinations using lubridate package in R, but I could not do it. I would like to obtain a dataframe like this:

```
   sampling date       ID    survival        days
1        1 04/03/2017 L4           0           0
2        1 04/03/2017 L5           0           0
3        1 04/03/2017 L6           0           0
4        2 15/03/2017 L4           0           11
5        2 15/03/2017 L5           1           11
6        2 15/03/2017 L6           0           11
7        3 23/03/2017 L4           0           19
8        3 23/03/2017 L6           1           19
```

Any suggestion?
 I will appreciate your help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you change the date to actual date class.

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

You can do this in base R :

```
df$days <- with(df, as.integer(date - ave(date, ID, FUN = min)))
```

`dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(days = as.integer(date - min(date)))
```

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, days := as.integer(date - min(date)), ID]
df

#   sampling       date ID survival days
#1:        1 2017-03-04 L4        0    0
#2:        1 2017-03-04 L5        0    0
#3:        1 2017-03-04 L6        0    0
#4:        2 2017-03-15 L4        0   11
#5:        2 2017-03-15 L5        1   11
#6:        2 2017-03-15 L6        0   11
#7:        3 2017-03-23 L4        0   19
#8:        3 2017-03-23 L6        1   19
```

Comment: Thank you! You and Neel gave me the best solution for my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the package chron, convert the date to a date object using the as.Date function, and then the dates will be subtractable.

I get your desired output using this code:

Input:

```
## to create your sample dataset -- so you can see what data types I started with
sampling <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
date <- c('04/03/2017','04/03/2017','04/03/2017','15/03/2017','15/03/2017','15/\
03/2017','23/03/2017','23/03/2017')
ID <- c('L4','L5','L6','L4','L5','L6','L4','L6')
survival <- c(0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1)

##this is the actual part of the code that calculates days since the first

library(chron)
df <- data.frame(sampling,date,ID,survival)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date,format='%d/%m/%Y') 
# convert date to chron fmt -- see
#    https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html

df$days <- as.integer(df$date - df$date[1])
```

Output:

```
> df
  sampling       date ID survival days
1        1 2017-03-04 L4        0    0
2        1 2017-03-04 L5        0    0
3        1 2017-03-04 L6        0    0
4        2 2017-03-15 L4        0   11
5        2 2017-03-15 L5        1   11
6        2 2017-03-15 L6        0   11
7        3 2017-03-23 L4        0   19
8        3 2017-03-23 L6        1   19
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems that the function doesn't calculate the number of days correctly. For example, in my data, there are new plants on different dates that the function did not recognize as a new record, or as a start from 0. But it is useful, I will explore this package. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using dplyr and lubridate

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

d %>% group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(days = difftime(time1 = date, time2 = min(date), units = "days"))
```

Output

```
sampling date       ID    survival days   
  <chr>    <date>     <chr>    <dbl> <drtn> 
1 1        2017-03-04 L4           0  0 days
2 1        2017-03-04 L5           0  0 days
3 1        2017-03-04 L6           0  0 days
4 2        2017-03-15 L4           0 11 days
5 2        2017-03-15 L5           1 11 days
6 2        2017-03-15 L6           0 11 days
7 3        2017-03-23 L4           0 19 days
8 3        2017-03-23 L6           1 19 days
```

Comment: my pleasure!!!. However, you should mark @RonakShah answer as accepted, because he gives you options to work directly with base R. **Lesser the package, Lesser the dependency**, except some standard once ;)

Comment: You are right, packages are useful but sometimes it is hard for me to remember too many commands and functions in R. So, I created functions with functions from packages haha.It is a matter of practice.